# How to integrate a NodeJS app on github into my React web app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to include an open source NodeJS (real time whiteboarding) app that I found on github into a create-react-app project that I'm working on. In my react app I would like to open up a window to this whiteboarding app so that users could interact with the whiteboard from within my react project. However, I have no idea how I would go about including this third-party app in my react app and there doesn't seem to be any resources online for "including nodejs app within react app".

A solution I can think of would be to host the whiteboarding app seperately and have an Iframe that links to that in my react app, but it seems like there would be a better way to do this.

How do other people usually include completely seperate web apps and integrate them into one?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to solve this, depending on how the whiteboard app is written.

Node.js is a server-side javascript runtime, so I assume (since I haven't seen the repo) that it is either serving HTML/CSS/js, or it is serving some sort of framework (Vue, React, etc). If it is using React, then it would be a matter of importing their components into your project, though that would require you to merge the projects and run their Node.js server somewhere for you to access. If it is just HTML/CSS/js you could copy that code into a react component, though you'd need to be careful to preserve any state or other logic that it relies on. If it is serving a different framework you may need to find a different project that fits your needs better, I don't know of a good way to mix frameworks that wouldn't get outrageously messy.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. I don't know why, but I assumed complete web apps would be easy to mix and match.